# Javascript Navigation Menu To only show up in certain Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, fixed

I am creating a one pager with a fixed Navigation Menu. I would like a sub nav to appear on scroll past a certain div. So is it possible have a fixed subnav just for a portion of a page
so say there are 10 divs. And divs from 2-5 require the sub nav to pop up
and then go away after div 5. Any examples, code, or articles would be greatly helpful!
Thank you in advance!

- Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is should be most of what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/XyxkW/

When you run it, scroll down to the fifth div and you will see the 'sub nav' fade in and out when it reaches the top of the window and when you scroll past both above and below div 5. You can replace any of the values with what ever values you need.